# combining output of two querys and displaying information in one list

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I currently have this page to select two lots of information and display it to the page it works by outputting two separate lists one list with check boxes to select an item to add to the database and the other list to show the titles that the user currently has but i need to simplify the output if possible to only display one list that has the information for the title on one line with wither no check box or a tick image next to the ones that the user is subscribed to or a cross next to the ones they are not.

i have added the code below and commented the query and output

```
 // Check to see if the form has been submitted
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

      // Declare shorthand for the id value if there is $_POST data
      $id = $_POST['userId'];

      // Connect to the database
      $objects->connect();

      // Create a variable full of the posted array sub
      $list = $_POST['sub'];

      // for each loop to insert each value into the database with the selected users informtion
      foreach ($list as  $value)  {

           // The query to run
           $listQuery='INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl_list (`userId`, `subId`) VALUES (\'' . $id . '\', \'' . $value . '\')';


           // Run the query
           $objects->query($listQuery);


      }

     }
     else{
      // Filter all of the $_GET data
      $objects->filterEverything($_GET);

      // Declare shorthand for the id value if there is $_GET data
      $id = $objects->clean['userId'];
     }
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Here is the first query to check if the user is subscribed to a title
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
     // This section will select any existing titles that the selected client is subbed to
     // Connect to the database
     $objects->connect();

     // The query to select the info for the clients current subb titles
     $exist = 'SELECT a.`subId`, a.`userId`, b.`subTitle`, b.`subId` FROM `tbl_list`a, `tbl_subs`b WHERE a.`subId` = b.`subId` AND a.`userId` =' . $id;

     // Create a variable and set it to the query
     $result = $objects->query($exist);

     // Consctuct the output
     $existOutput = '';

     // Loop through the results and create the output with the count
     while($result = $objects->result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){

      $existOutput .= '<p>' . $result['subId'] . '' . $result['subTitle'] . '</p>';

     }


    // Select the chosen users information from the database
    // Connect to the database
    $objects->connect();

    // query the database
    $query = 'SELECT `userId`,
                     `firstName`,
             `lastName`
           FROM     `tbl_user`
           WHERE `userId` =' . $id;

    // Run the query
    $objects->query($query);

    //Store the results returned from the database
    $row = $objects->result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

    // Create the users output
    $output = '' . $row['firstName'] . ' ' . $row['lastName'] . '';
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Here is the second query to create a list of titles with check boxes to add to the users list Note the list still displays the titles that the user is subscribed to
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
     // This section selects the selected users name
     // Connect to the database
     $objects->connect();

     // Query for the database
     $selectionQuery = 'SELECT `subId`, `subTitle` FROM `tbl_subs`';

     // Run the query
     $objects->query($selectionQuery);

     // Create the output
     $subOutput = '';
     $subOutput .= $objects->openForm();
     while($row = $objects->result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){

      $subOutput .= '<input type="checkbox" " name="sub[]" value="' . $row['subId'] . '" />' . $row['subTitle'] . '<br />';

     }
     $subOutput .= $objects->makeInput('userId','hidden','none');
     $subOutput .= $objects->makeSubmitButton('submit','Edit','submit');
     $subOutput .= $objects->closeForm();

}
else{
    // If the user is not logged in then redirect to the login page
    header("Location:index.php");
}

//Include the header for the page
include_once '../includes/header.php'
?>
     <!--  The Body section starts here  -->
     <div id="body">

      <div class="bodyBox">

               <!--  The left side of the body  -->
               <div class="bodyLeft left">

                    <div class="cmsContainer">

                        <h2>Manage Subs</h2>

                        <div class="cmsMargin">
                  <p>Manage the subscriptions for <?php echo $output; ?></p>

                  <?php echo $subOutput; ?>
                  <?php echo $listTest; ?>

                  <p><a class="link left" href="index.php">Control Panel</a></p>

                  <p><?php echo $existOutput; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need an Outer Join:

```
SELECT a.`subId`, a.`userId`, b.`subTitle`, b.`subId`,
  CASE -- check if there was a matching b.`subId`
     WHEN b.`subId` IS NOT NULL THEN 'x' ELSE ' ' END
  END
FROM `tbl_list`a LEFT JOIN `tbl_subs`b 
ON a.`subId` = b.`subId` 
WHERE a.`userId` =' . $id
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply i am unfamiliar with the use of case i have tried to use this but must not be getting something for i only get T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING here is the query

Comment: $exist = 'SELECT a.`subId`, a.`userId`, b.`subTitle`, b.`subId` CASE  WHEN b.`subId` = a.`subId` THEN '.$x.' ELSE '' END
  END
FROM `tbl_list`a LEFT JOIN `tbl_subs`b
ON a.`subId` = b.`subId` WHERE a.`userId`='. $id;

Comment: There's a coma missing before the CASE. And you probably need to escape the empty string? ELSE '''' END?